# making impementation of parcelable classes

Tags: java, android

my app crashes when navigating through the fragments. the logcat error tells BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class ge.mobility.weather.entity.City. so  I need my classes to implement parcelable and then i want to pass a City object through the fragment.

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class City implements Parcelable {
    private String code;
    private String name;

    private List<CityWeather> weathers ;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public List<CityWeather> getWeathers() {
        if(weathers == null) {
            weathers = new ArrayList<CityWeather>();
        }
        return weathers;
    }
    public void addCityWeather(CityWeather w) {
        getWeathers().add(w);
    }

    public void addCityWeathers(List<CityWeather> w) {
        getWeathers().addAll(w);
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and the secnd class

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class CityWeather  {

    private String date;
    private String weatherDescription;
    private int weatherCode;
    private String currentTemperature;
    private String minTemperature;
    private String maxTemperature;
    private String humadity;
    private String wind;
    private String day;
    private String temperatureUnit;

    public String getTemperatureUnit(){
        return temperatureUnit;
    }
    public void setTemperatureUnit(String temperatureUnit){
        this.temperatureUnit = temperatureUnit;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getWeatherDescription() {
        return weatherDescription;
    }
    public void setWeatherDescription(String weatherDescription) {
        this.weatherDescription = weatherDescription;
    }
    public int getWeatherCode() {
        return weatherCode;
    }
    public void setWeatherCode(int weatherCode) {
        this.weatherCode = weatherCode;
    }
    public String getCurrentTemperature() {
        return currentTemperature;
    }
    public void setCurrentTemperature(String currentTemperature) {
        this.currentTemperature = currentTemperature;
    }
    public String getMinTemperature() {
        return minTemperature;
    }
    public void setMinTemperature(String minTemperature) {
        this.minTemperature = minTemperature;
    }
    public String getMaxTemperature() {
        return maxTemperature;
    }
    public void setMaxTemperature(String maxTemperature) {
        this.maxTemperature = maxTemperature;
    }
    public String getHumadity() {
        return humadity;
    }
    public void setHumadity(String humadity) {
        this.humadity = humadity;
    }
    public String getWind() {
        return wind;
    }
    public void setWind(String wind) {
        this.wind = wind;
    }
    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }
    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try implement `Parcelable` then you must have to create an obeject named CREATOR inside your class which implementing the `Parcelable` interface as example for your `City` class...

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<City> CREATOR = new Creator<City>() {

    @Override
    public City[] newArray(int size) {
        return new City[size];
    }

    @Override
    public City createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new City(in);
    }
};
```